Issues Connecting to MySQL Server with MySQL Workbench Installed from .deb Package
I’m facing issues with MySQL Workbench on my Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS system. I initially installed the Snap version, which worked well for running commands but could not open or display the partitions created in my Windows installation (partition type: "Basic Data").
To address this, I switched to the .deb package from the official MySQL repository. While this version correctly shows the Windows partitions, I am encountering a connection error when trying to connect to the local MySQL server. The error message is as follows:
Authentication plugin 'mysql_native_password' cannot load: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mysql/libmysqlcpconn10/plugin/mysql_native_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I have tried removing and reinstalling the .deb version multiple times, but the problem persists.
Here are the details of my setup:

Ubuntu version: 24.04.1 LTS
MySQL version: 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.24.04.2
MySQL Workbench version: mysql-workbench-community_8.0.40-1ubuntu24.04_amd64.deb

I checked the MySQL server status with the following command:
sudo systemctl status mysql

Here’s the output:
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-10-17 10:56:12 IST; 1h 29min ago
    Process: 1291 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1334 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server is operational"
      Tasks: 40 (limit: 9133)
     Memory: 267.3M (peak: 441.0M swap: 122.6M swap peak: 122.6M)
        CPU: 34.816s
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─1334 /usr/sbin/mysqld

The service is active and operational, but MySQL Workbench from the .deb package is still unable to connect.
Error Screenshots

Snap Version Error:
Code working img:

Partition not visible in Snap:


.deb Version Error:




Video of the Problem
You can view a video demonstrating the problem here: Google Drive Video
I would appreciate any guidance on troubleshooting these issues with both versions of MySQL Workbench.
Thank you!

The problem is that you cannot use the root MySQL account without elevated privileges. The simplest solution would be to create a new account in MySQL (call it admin or anything that you’d like) and grant it all permissions. This was you can connect to MySQL from the .deb install and still do all the admin-level stuff you need to do
